# Question about C++ DLL function use in C#

Tags: c#, dll, c++-cli

I have a DLL made in C++ that is then used in a C# program. the C# program references the DLL and i call the classes and can use the functions defined in the DLL.

Now i want to add other functions to the DLL so i can run C++ code in C#. I Follow the example of how the other functions in the DLL are defined; .h and .cpp and i create a new function that executes code. I put it in the same places as the previously define functions, but when i put the DLL in my C# code my function is not there. when i create an instance of the DLL class my function is not a part of it.

I put it in the .h as a public function of the class and gave it code to run in the .cpp but its not found.

Why can't my C# program see the function i made even though its following the same suite as the other functions?

**UPDATE**

code.h:

```
#pragma once

#include <windows.h>
#include <PvDisplayWnd.h>
#include <vfw.h>
#include "NPvResult.h"
#include "NPvDeviceInfo.h"
#include "NPvBuffer.h"
#include <string>

using namespace System;
using namespace System::Runtime::InteropServices;

public ref class NPvDisplayWnd
{
public :
    NPvDisplayWnd();
    bool Handle();
    NPvResult^ ShowModeless(long locx, long locy, long x, long y);
    NPvResult^ ShowModal();
    NPvResult^ NPvDisplayWnd::Create();
    int^ Display( NPvBuffer^ aBuffer, int^ x);
    NPvResult^ Work( const std::string afilename, unsigned short asizex, unsigned short asizey, unsigned short aBPP, double aFPS);
    NPvResult^ Close();
    NPvResult^ DoEvents();
}
```

code.cpp:

```
#include "NPvDisplayWnd.h"

NPvDisplayWnd::NPvDisplayWnd(){code}
NPvResult^ NPvDisplayWnd::Create(){code}
bool NPvDisplayWnd::Handle()
NPvResult^ NPvDisplayWnd::ShowModeless(long locx, long locy, long x, long y){code}
NPvResult^ NPvDisplayWnd::ShowModal(){code}
int^ NPvDisplayWnd::Display( NPvBuffer^ aBuffer, int^ x){code}
NPvResult^ NPvDisplayWnd::DoEvents(){code}
NPvResult^ NPvDisplayWnd::Work( const std::string aFileName, unsigned short aSizeX, unsigned short aSizeY, unsigned short aBPP, double aFPS){code}
NPvResult^ NPvDisplayWnd::Close(){code}
```

The function that i added was the Work() function. if i build this and place it in my C# code, it sees all the functions except work. To make sure i was using the right .dll, i changed the name of ShowModeless() to ShowModeless__F() and rebuilt it and added it to my C# and the change carried over, but i still didn't see my Work() function.

Comment: Do you have links to the examples you're working from?

Comment: This is not a C++ dll at all; this is C++/CLI, which is a different language (though similar) from C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Windows, you must explicitly export symbols in order for users to be able to access them via DLLs. This is done using the `__declspec(export)` syntax. This is needed during compilation and linking of the DLL.

---

Now that we know you're using C++/CLI instead of regular C++, we can see a problem. `Work` takes a `std::string`. But `Work` is intended to be a managed function, and managed code cannot take a `std::string` as a parameter. You need to take a managed string type instead.

Comment: The DLL works fine without my added function. i even picked a function renamed it in the .h and the .cpp and gave it to my C# app and it saw the change. this same function is only ever referenced in the .h and the .cpp. I followed that same setup for this added function and it didnt work

Comment: @Grant: Then there's a good chance that you're not loading the DLL you think you are. You need to make sure that, after building the DLL, it gets into the path and overwrites the old one, or otherwise overrides it. And if that's not the problem, then you're going to have to show us your code. The C++ .h and .cpp code for functions (ones that work and ones that don't), as well as the C# code you use for loading them.

Comment: updated with code. I just reference it in my C# code and instantiate the DLL Class

Answer (score 0):

A native C++ class cannot be imported in C#. You need to utilize C++/CLI feature in existing C++ DLL so that managed clients (like C#) can import the classes.

```
namespace XX
{ 
  public ref class YourClass{...};
}
```

It will export managed class `YourClass` under `XX` namespace. You need to use `/CLR` compiler flag.

You may compile set of CPP files as managed, and set of other files as unmanaged. Managed classes cannot contain unmanaged stuff (unless it is declared pointer).